# How do I configure the shutdown policy for Scala ExecutionContexts?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, executioncontext

I recently came across some odd behavior on a machine where `map`ing a function that returns `Future[T]` was executing sequentially. This same problem does not occur on other machines: work is interleaved as one would expect. I later discovered that this was likely because Scala was being a little too smart and choosing an `ExecutionContext` that matched the machine's resources: one core, one worker.

Here's some simple code that reproduces the problem:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val ss = List("the", "quick", "brown", "fox",
              "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog")

def r(s: String) : Future[String] = future {
        for (i <- 1 to 10) yield {
                println(String.format("r(%s) waiting %s more seconds...",
                        s, (10 - i).toString))
                Thread.sleep(1000)

        }
        s.reverse
}

val f_revs = ss.map { r(_) }

println("Look ma, no blocking!")

val rev = f_revs.par.map { Await.result(_, Duration.Inf) }.mkString(" ")

println(rev)
```

Running this on the machine exhibiting the strange behavior produces sequential output like this:

```
Look ma, no blocking!
r(the) waiting 9 more seconds...
r(the) waiting 8 more seconds...
r(the) waiting 7 more seconds...
```

Providing a custom `ExecutionContext`:

```
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(pool)
```

allows the threads to interleave on this machine. But I have a new problem now: the thread pool does not shutdown, causing the program to hang indefinitely.  Apparently, this is the [expected behavior](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) for `FixedThreadPool`s, and I can shut it down by putting `pool.shutdown()` somewhere.

Call me stubborn, but I don't want to have to tell the thread pool to shutdown.  Is there a way to configure the pool to shutdown when all of the queues are empty (possibly after some delay) just like it works with the default pool?  I've looked through the `ExecutionContext` documentation, but I'm not finding what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Java 7 has some additional `ExecutorService`s, in particular, a [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) that does what I want (i.e., no need to `shutdown()` the pool).

Changing the pool to the following is sufficient to achieve what I want:

```
val pool = new java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool(5)
```

Java 8 apparently has [even more services](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Answer (score 2):

Scala uses its own fork-join implementation which behaves differently from the Java ones, hence the different behavior between the default `ExecutionContext` and the one you created with `Executors`.

An easier way to do what you want would be to set the following System properties to configure the default `ExecutionContext`:

1. `scala.concurrent.context.minThreads` to impose a minimum number of threads. Defaults to `1`.
2. `scala.concurrent.context.numThreads` to set the number of thread. Defaults to `x1`.
3. `scala.concurrent.context.maxThreads` to impose a maximum number of threads. Defaults to `x1`.

Each of these can either be a number, or a number preceded by `x`, to indicate a multiple of the number of processors. To increase the number of threads, you have to change both `numThreads` and `maxThreads`. In you case, setting both to `x2` should work.